# HTTP Post data from Arduino uno using WiFi

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

[image: All commands are shows as success but there is no response from the webpage to that data is posting.]Please help me to post data from arduino uno to a webpage using wifi(ESP-01) module. I try with AT commands it didn't give the response from my webpage

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#define DEBUG true

#define RX 10
#define TX 11
String WIFI_SSID = "*****";       // Your WiFi ssid
String PASSWORD = "*****";         // Password
//String DEVICE_SECRET_KEY  = "**";

//String PATH = "/v1/events";
//String PORT = "8000";
//String HOST = "http://10.**.***.66:8000/data";

String HOST = "10.**.240.**";
String PATH = "/data";
String PORT = "8000";

String response;
int countTrueCommand;
int countTimeCommand;
boolean found = false;

SoftwareSerial esp8266(RX, TX);
StaticJsonBuffer<200> jsonBuffer;
JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.createObject();

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  esp8266.begin(115200);
  esp8266.println("AT");
  Serial.println(esp8266.read());
  sendCommandToESP8266("AT", 5, "OK");
   sendCommandToESP8266("AT+CWMODE=3", 5, "OK");
  sendCommandToESP8266("AT+CWJAP=\"" + WIFI_SSID + "\",\"" + PASSWORD + "\"", 20, "OK");
}

void loop()
{
  root["key"] =  "sdfsdfsd";
  String key;
  root.printTo(key);
  String postRequest =   "POST " + PATH  + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                         "Host: " + HOST + "\r\n" +
                         "Accept: *" + "/" + "*\r\n" +
                         "Content-Length: " + key.length() + "\r\n" +
                         "Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
                         "\r\n" + key;
  Serial.print("pst:" + postRequest);
  sendCommandToESP8266("AT+CIPMUX=1", 5, "OK");
  sendCommandToESP8266("AT+CIPSTART=0,\"TCP\",\"" + HOST + "\"," + PORT, 15, "OK");
  String cipSend = "AT+CIPSEND=0," + String(postRequest.length());//GET /test.php?Data=2\r\nHost:192.168.1.13\r\n\r\n
  sendCommandToESP8266(cipSend, 4, ">");
  sendData(postRequest);

  while (esp8266.available())
  {
    if (esp8266.find("+IPD,"))
    {
//      String msg;
      esp8266.find("?");
//      msg = esp8266.readStringUntil(' ');
      response = esp8266.readStringUntil(' ');
      Serial.print(response);
      Serial.println();
    }
  }
  printResponse;



  //  sendCommandToESP8266("AT+CIPCLOSE=0", 5, "OK");
}

void sendCommandToESP8266(String command, int maxTime, char readReplay[]) {
  Serial.print(countTrueCommand);
  Serial.print(". at command => ");
  Serial.print(command);
  Serial.print(" ");
  while (countTimeCommand < (maxTime * 1))
  {
    esp8266.println(command);
    if (esp8266.find(readReplay))
    {
      found = true;
      break;
    }

    countTimeCommand++;
  }

  if (found == true)
  {
    Serial.println("Success");
    countTrueCommand++;
    countTimeCommand = 0;
  }

  if (found == false)
  {
    Serial.println("Fail");
    countTrueCommand = 0;
    countTimeCommand = 0;
  }

  found = false;
}

void sendData(String postRequest) {
  Serial.println(postRequest);
  Serial.println();
  esp8266.println(postRequest);
  delay(15000);
  countTrueCommand++;
}

void printResponse() {
  while (esp8266.available()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println(esp8266.readStringUntil('\n'));
  }
}
```

Please help me to get the response from the webpage using this code.

Comment: SoftwareSerial doesn't work at 115200 baud. change the baud rate in AT firmware and for SoftwareSerial to 9600 baud.

Comment: @Juraj i try by changing the baud rate but still there is no response from my webpage

Comment: @Juraj Or please let me know that if there is any another way to post data from arduino uno by using wifi.(ESP01 module).   I see many programs that are using ethernet and anothehr wifi modules.

Comment: if you want something like Ethernet library you can use my WiFiEspAT library. but it requires to change the AT firmware in esp-01 to version 1.7 https://github.com/jandrassy/WiFiEspAT/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @Juraj can i use the above mentioned library with arduino uno and esp01?   Iam a beginner in arduino programming that's why asking about these questions.

Comment: the WiFiEspAT library handles the AT commands for you. the wiring is same has you have now

Comment: @Juraj I just want to know how to change the version of esp-01 to versio 1.7. Is esp-01 works when version is not changed?

Comment: with old AT firmware you can use the old WiFiEsp library.

Comment: @Juraj _https://github.com/bportaluri/WiFiEsp/blob/master/examples/ConnectWPA/ConnectWPA.ino_ I try to use this code but it shows as wifi shield is not present.

Comment: set 9600 baud in AT firmware. the libraries are in Library Manager in IDE

Comment: @Juraj when i use the library   i got the below output on serial monitor.                                                                      `[WiFiEsp] Initializing ESP module
[WiFiEsp] >>> TIMEOUT >>>
[WiFiEsp] >>> TIMEOUT >>>
[WiFiEsp] >>> TIMEOUT >>>
[WiFiEsp] >>> TIMEOUT >>>
[WiFiEsp] >>> TIMEOUT >>>
[WiFiEsp] Cannot initialize ESP module
[WiFiEsp] >>> TIMEOUT >>>
[WiFiEsp] No tag found
WiFi shield not present`

Comment: did you set the baud rate to 9600 baud in firmware and in sketch?

Comment: @juraj Sorry!! I forget to change the baud rate. Now wifi is getting connected using esp library. And can you please help me to post data from arduino using this library and how to get the response back from the server.

Comment: @juraj when i try to post data from arduino to webpage it will not sending the data and not connecting to server serial monitor shows as :                              
 `Starting connection to server...
[WiFiEsp] Connecting to xxx.xx.xxx.xx
[WiFiEsp] >>> TIMEOUT >>>
[WiFiEsp] >>> TIMEOUT >>>
[WiFiEsp] No tag found

Disconnecting from server...
`

Answer (score 1):

Step 1) Upload software serial from example and send AT, you should get reply as AT OK if your connections are correct.
Step 2) Once your connections are correct and if you are uploading the given code then make sure you put your SSID, password, and Server IP which would be the three Strings: HOST, PATH and PORT.

You could alternatively check your server first by sending it a GET or POST using your browser or another software for testing API's(I personally use POSTMAN).

Proceed further once you perform these checks.

Comment: I tried this and still not getting response from the webpage. Also API have no problems when i check it.

Comment: Did you try the AT command check? Upload software serial and you can manually enter AT commands and check where you are going wrong.

Comment: I have 2 esp-01 modules with me. I think one of my esp is corrupted. But other one is working when check by AT command.

Comment: Now you can check each command that is being used via Software Serial. For example according to your code if u send "AT+CWMODE=3" u will get a reply OK. You can do a complete post request just using software serial by inputting commands one after the other. Its a good practice to do this as it will help you understand at what point your code is going wrong.

Comment: I tried by sending all the AT commands and i stop where AT+CIPSTART=0,"TCP","xx.xxx.xxx.xx","port" from this command i got error message. what can i do to make it correct?

Comment: Try this command AT+CIPSTART="TCP","192.168.3.116",8080 Change the server ip and port accordingly. The 0 indicates id of the connection in AT+CIPSTART=0,"TCP","xx.xxx.xxx.xx","port" . I found the id being used only for a UDP connection in the espressif at command example. I referred this [link](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/4b-esp8266_at_command_examples_en.pdf). Did you execute the AT commands in the sequence given in your question?

Comment: I check with the AT commands. But   AT+CIPSTART="TCP","192.168.3.116",8080 this command is not working. I didin't understand what the problem is. All the other commands before AT+CIPSTART is working with the module.